# Why use a sandwich press instead of an oven or pan?

Tags: equipment, sandwich

I often make hot sandwiches. Usually I just put butter on the outsides of the bread, then put them in the oven just until the cheese melts. I see other people just put the sandwiches in a pan with butter, and flip it a few times.

I notice the store selling sandwich presses, but am confused by the purpose. They do not seem more convenient than an oven, because that just adds another item to wash, and they seem to smash the sandwich.

Is there some advantage to using a sandwich press in terms of convenience or of taste?

Comment: They press the sandwich, making it thinner and sometimes adding ridges. It's a texture thing, mostly.

Comment: There are sandwiches where smashing the sandwich is desired ... cuban sandiwches, panini, etc.  If you just look at your basic 'grilled cheese', you have significant differences in the crust if you toast it in the oven, cook it on a pan or griddle, or cook it under pressure.

Comment: We tend to put a piece of oven paper between the sandwich and the sandwich press, so there's no extra item to wash.

Comment: I usually wrap fireplace bricks in foil, heat them up in the oven, and use them to press the sandwiches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is really no advantage or disadvantage to using a sandwich press. This is more a choice of preference from person to person.

For me, a sandwich press is preferable as it toast the bread on both sides simultaneously, so you get an even toast on both sides, and it also presses the sandwich together so that it does not fall apart. A sandwich press also heats up faster than an oven (note, I'm talking about electrical ovens that is commenly used in RSA) and consumes much less electricity to do the same job.

So yes, this is all about what you prefer and what works best for you

Comment: It's funny, this issue just came up in chat. No question, it comes down to personal preference. Of the two people involved in the discussion, the pan-on-the-stove method was much preferred to the press for grilled cheese. However, a muffuletta or similarly over-filled sandwich just begs for the press (IMO).